# Flashing Nordic nrf52 with FTDI

Tags: ftdi

I have the [nRF52832](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf52832-breakout-board-hookup-guide?_ga=2.223640283.1536702341.1524450104-15137781.1524450104#programming-via-bootloader), connected via [FT232RL FTDI](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B014Y1IMNM/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and it fails when I try to upload a firmware file to it. I'm using PlatformIO in Atom. Following instructions at 
[Get started with Arduino and Nordic nRF52-DK](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/tutorials/nordicnrf52/arduino_debugging_unit_testing.html).

**platform.ini**

```
[env:nrf52_dk]
platform = nordicnrf52
board = nrf52_dk
framework = arduino
build_flags = -DNRF52_S132
lib_deps =
  BLEPeripheral
upload_protocol = blackmagic
```

Code builds fine, but the upload to the Nordic fails.

**Output**

```
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: blackmagic, cmsis-dap, jlink, mbed, nrfjprog, stlink
CURRENT: upload_protocol = blackmagic
MethodWrapper(["upload"], [".pioenvs/nrf52_dk/firmware.hex"])
Auto-detected: /dev/cu.usbserial-00000000
arm-none-eabi-gdb -nx --batch -ex "target extended-remote /dev/cu.usbserial-00000000" -ex "monitor swdp_scan" -ex "attach 1" -ex load -ex compare-sections -ex kill /Users/thomas/workspace/Arduino/ble-blink/.pioenvs/nrf52_dk/firmware.elf
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
Don't know how to attach.  Try "help target".
You can't do that when your target is `exec'
Section .text, range 0x1c000 -- 0x1cbdc: matched.
Section .ARM.exidx, range 0x1cbdc -- 0x1cbe4: matched.
warning: One or more sections of the target image does not match
the loaded file
The program is not being run.
Section .data, range 0x1cbe4 -- 0x1d020: MIS-MATCHED!
```

Comment: You selected a blackmagic probe, not an FTDI solution.  Your programming software's list of supported interfaces doesn't include any FTDI parts.  So first you'll need to be specific about *which* FTDI part, then you'll need to find a build of the software that supports it.  Or get a cheap STLINK - it works with some non-ST parts including this at least with OpenOCD, but the better FTDI parts work with that as well.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I edited my question to add the [FTDI](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B014Y1IMNM/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) I used. I assumed they were all the same from the software's perspective.

Comment: You're still not going to get anywhere until you tell the software to use the adapter you have.  Also the FT232RL is a poor choice for this - it might be *possible* but at best it will be slow.  People usually use the FT2232H or FT4232H.  But you may find it easier with a cheap stlink.

Comment: Why not use the nRF52DK with it's on-board J-link to flash the external board?

Comment: Cause he didn't mention he has that kit.

Comment: I ordered the [ST-Link](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01J7N3RE6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), and am going to try that soon! Will report back here with progress.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has abandoned this course of action and purchased an ST-Link adapter instead

Comment: Yeah that's cool @chris. I haven't tried the ST-LINK yet, but can open another question when I do, if necessary

Comment: Hopefully you will tell the software what probe you actually have next time, instead of repeating the mistake that lead to this question...